# In Swift, how can I trigger another view, such as a uilalertview or a modal popover, by clicking on a link in uiwebview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a uiwebview that uses `.loadHTMLstring(string, baseURL: nil )`. I am iterating through nested objects to display words in the uiwebview with this `let string = "<h2>\(object.word)</h2>"` in a for-loop.

I want to do something like this: `let string = "<h2><a href="\(object.definition) target="UIAlertView">\(object.word)</a></h2>"`

I would like to let the user click on any word in the uiwebview and have it trigger an alert or a modal popup that displays the definition of the word.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in Swift?

Comment: Are you trying to use the apple dictionary for definitions or your own?

Comment: I am wanting to use my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to let the user click on any word in the uiwebview and have it trigger an alert or a modal popup that displays the definition of the word.

Set the web view's delegate and implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. Now your code is called whenever a link in the web view is clicked. And that means you can read the request and do anything you like.

Comment: Is this for Swift? I am using Swift. What Objective-C code are you referring to?

Comment: Okay, fine, I deleted the word "Objective-C". I was just trying to make it clear that this was happening in your app, not inside JavaScript or the web view.

Comment: Example code from my book is here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch11p551webview/ch24p825webview/WebViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

You'll meet some encoding problem I guess ... but here's a way to get you definition.
Instead of a custom target you could use a custom url scheme.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

let definition = "My Definition is ...".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let string = "<h2><a href=\"/?My Definition is ...\" target=\"UIAlertView\">CLICK ME</a></h2>"
func testFunc() {

}

//MARK: WebView Delegate
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    switch navigationType {
    case .LinkClicked:
        if let theHref = request.URL.query?.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding {
            println(theHref)
        }
    default:
        break
    }

    return true
}


//MARK: View Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.webView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: NSURL())
    self.webView.delegate = self

}
}
```

Comment: I need help understanding and implementing your suggestion here. Can we talk or chat sometime?